# How to set a random color(lets say green) after generating a random position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I'm solving a Knights Tour problem and I want to set green color on the field of Knights "first move" = "first appearance".

This is what it looks like:
[image: This is what it looks like]

I have a 8x8 table and my Knights appears randomly on the board and I can't figure out how to set his first appearance to be green.

```
var boardSize = 8;
var currentCoords = {x: Math.round(Math.random() * 7), y: Math.round(Math.random() * 7)};
var count = 1;
```

This is generating part.

```
$('table tr').eq(currentCoords.y).find('td').eq(currentCoords.x).html('<span style="font-size:50px;color:blue;margin-left:10%;">&#9816;</span>');
```

And this is when knight appears on the board.

If anyone could help I would appreciate it.
Thanks in advance.

Desired result:
[image: What I want to achieve]

Comment: Please clarify what it is you would like to be green.

Comment: So, a king should appear - in green or in a random color?

Comment: Also, perhaps a screenshot? More parts of the code? You're generating something that has a blue color, could that be the problem?

Comment: Try `<span style="font-size:50px;color:blue;background:green;margin-left:10%;">&#9816;</span>`?

Comment: This is what I need http://i.stack.imgur.com/fWoNl.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so you want the background of the square to be green. The "desired result" screenshot clarified that, thank you.

You already know how to get the table cell, in order to put the knight into the cell.

You need to use a similar jQuery call to get the cell:

```
$('table tr').eq(currentCoords.y).find('td').eq(currentCoords.x)
```

And then instead of the `.html()` call that you use to place the knight, you need to use a `.css()` call to change the styles of the cell itself.

The style you need to set is `background`, so you'd do this:

```
$('table tr').eq(currentCoords.y).find('td').eq(currentCoords.x).css({'background':'green'});
```

immediately before or after your line to place the knight.

For a bonus point, since there's a lot of duplicated code between the two lines of code, you can simplify things further by moving the jQuery part to get the table cell into a separate variable, and then referencing it twice, like so:

```
var $firstCell = $('table tr').eq(currentCoords.y).find('td').eq(currentCoords.x);
$firstCell.css({'background':'green'});
$firstCell.html('<span style="font-size:50px;color:blue;margin-left:10%;">&#9816;</span>');
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: This is awesome thanks. But maybe I wasnt so clear. I only need first square to be green. http://imgur.com/KMuuQbJ

Comment: the solution I gave should only affect the same single square that the knight is placed on. If you don't want subequent squares to be affected, then only call the `.css()` part once.

Comment: How do i call it only once? Tried using .one() didn't work very well.

Comment: Try having a variable that you set after calling it, and only calling it if the variable isn't set. (It's fairly basic stuff, this; you should be able to figure it out)